# A not-so-typical marble question

Tags: probability

In a bag are 8 white marbles and 5 red. Two marbles are drawn from the bag.
What is the probability that both marbles are white if we know that one of them is white?
The answer is 0,412 but I don't know how to get there :(

Comment: Not to be rude but this seems pretty typical to me. What have you tried>

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$P(B \text{ happens given } A \text{ happens})=\frac{P(A\text{ and } B \text{ happen})}{P(A \text{ happens})}$$
In symbolic notation:
$$P(B|A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$$